# What is the cardinality of the subset of [0,1] consisting of infinite decimal expansions with only the digits 2 and 5?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Wouldn't this be uncountably infinite because ie, 
$$x_1=0.222225..., x_2=0.555555552..., x_3=0.5255...,$$ 
and if we keep going on...there can be $2^{\aleph_0}$ combinations. Then the cardinality would just be $\aleph_1$?

Comment: what you say is basically correct, but I suggest you work on your wording of it before you submit your answer.

Comment: Only if you assume the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Is there a way I can prove it using Cantor's diagonalization method? I want to provide an answer that shows a proof of some sort

Comment: Find a bijection between this set and $2^{\bf N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Same as the reals.

Map $2 \to 0$ and $5 \to 1$
and consider the result
as a binary number.

Comment: I can tell the set is uncountable because I can create a number based on Cantor's diagonalization method but how do i conclude by mapping what the cardinality is?